# Prove that if $D$ is a field, then $\phi: D\to Q$ is an isomorphism of rings.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

The question is as follows:

Let $D$ be an integral domain. Let $Q$ be its field of fractions and $\phi :
D \to Q$ be the canonical map of $D$ into $Q$.

Prove that, if $D$ is a
field, then $\phi$ is surjective. Also prove that if $D$ is a field, then $\phi$ is an isomorphism of rings.

My confusion begins at if $D$ is a field, I thought it was an integral domain? I understand that $Q$ will be a field after we use $\phi$ to map $D$ to $Q$ but if $D$ is already a field then well we obviously don't have 1-1. I know the standard method to map say $C$ or $H$ to a field in the reals $(a,e)$ just map each second term to $e$ and each first term to its real part in wherever you are. Can someone help me construct this mapping?

Comment: A field is an integral domain, no? The canonical mapping $\phi$ sends $d\in D$ to (the equivalence class of) the fraction $d/1$. Your task is to show that if $a,b\in D, b\neq0$, then for some element $c\in D$ you have $\phi(c)=c/1=a/b$. How would you do that?

Comment: Lol id want to write a as some integer w = lcm(a,b)

Comment: ?? May be there aren't necessarily any integers around? $D$ can be any field! And the task was to find $c$! The elements $a$ and $b$ were given.

Comment: can i just pick a=c b=1?

Comment: No. $a$ and $b$ were both given. You can only choose $c$. Hint: at this point you have to use the assumption that $D$ is a field, not just any old integral domain.

Comment: An example: If $D$ is the field of rational numbers, and you are given $a=3$, $b=2$, then $c=3/2$ works for the following reasons: 
$$A)\quad \phi(3/2)=\frac{3/2}1=\frac32,\qquad B)\quad 3/2\in D.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems somewhat poorly phrased. If $D$ is a field, then it is surely an integral domain. Moreover $D=Q$, so that canonical map is, in fact, the identity isomorphism.

To see this, the canonical map $\phi$ described takes $a\mapsto\frac{a}{1}$. The inverse map, $\phi^{-1}$, would just take $\frac{a}{1}\mapsto a$.  This is clearly an identity map.

Comment: ok why is this mapping not 1-1 then?

Comment: @Faust7: Why wouldn't this mapping be 1-1?

Comment: if youe in a field you have redundant elements don't you like $a^{2}/a$ ?

Comment: But $a^2/a$ and $a/1$ are then the same element. In both $D$ and $Q(D)$.

Comment: We also cannot have a fraction of the form $a^2/a$ because, in the field of fractions, we actually have equivalence classes. $a/b\sim c/d\iff ad=bc$. So in this case, $a^2/a\sim a/1\iff a^2=a^2$, which is clearly true.

Comment: @Frank Certainly $\,a^2/a\,$ (or its class) *is* a fraction. Probably you mean that it is not a *proper* fraction over $D.\ \ $